# How do I copy json dictionary values to other json files with unique keys?

Tags: python, json

I have a JSON file with a dictionary. Something simple like

```
{ "1": "Filepath/image.png",
"2": "Filepath/image.png"
etc. }
```

Then I have 3 other JSON dictionary files with unique keys (RFID tag numbers).
I want the copy the values of the first file and overwrite the values of the other 3 JSON files. I know the keys I want for the 3 files, so I have them in 3 lists.

This is the last script I tried to achieve this, but it just determined the keys didn't match.

```
import json
import os
import glob
import time

# Get a list of all the files in the folder
files = glob.glob("json/*")

# Sort the list of files by modification time
files.sort(key=lambda x: os.path.getmtime(x))

# Get the filepath of the newest file
newest_file = files[-1]

print(newest_file)

# Open the newest file and read its contents
with open(newest_file, 'r') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

# List of keys to use for each file
keys_1 = ["13603414011682", "1360739520482", "136010319878103", "136073122213110", "136034217194177", "1360352372244",
 "1360739715155", "136072188183203", "136034163207198", "1360738615152", "1201261612531", "136034225204135", "136034230076"]
keys_2 = ["136073152053", "136034158129181", "13603412514289", "1360345793206", "136034148129191", "136010459115168", "136034145143180", "1360739170220", "1360351355527", "13603410960251","1360355159163", "13601049817949", "13603422660116"]
keys_3 = ["136075353245", "1360743335192", "13601043613070", "1360738365211", "136073133188248", "136034184248234", "13603571150122", "1360341385624", "136074741236", "136074211164181", "111", "222", "333"]

# Create the first file
subset_1 = {}
for i, key in enumerate(keys_1):
    subset_1[key] = data.get(key, f'Key not found at index {i}')

with open('json/charlie.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(subset_1, f)

# Create the second file
subset_2 = {}
for i, key in enumerate(keys_2):
    subset_2[key] = data.get(key, f'Key not found at index {i}')

with open('json/hagrid.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(subset_2, f)

# Create the third file
subset_3 = {}
for i, key in enumerate(keys_3):
    subset_3[key] = data.get(key, f'Key not found at index {i}')

with open('json/junior.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(subset_3, f)
```

Comment: Are you sure the keys exist in the first file?

Comment: Does the first file really have keys that start from `1` instead of matching the RFID tag numbers? How are these supposed to be matched up with the RFID tags?

Comment: Also are you sure you want to use JSON for this? SQLite might be a better option for this and comes with python out of the box... You can then just write SQL to pair the data

Comment: Ok, I could have included more context. 
The main Ultrasound Simulator script is looking for a dictionary with a RFID tag as the key, and value as the filepath to the gif to display. 
I have another script where I can select a file for 13 'tags', and saves it as a "preset" JSON dictionary. Row labels as keys, filepath as values. 

I was hoping there was a way to take the first JSON, and maybe using index or something, copy those values and replace the values of 3 other JSON dictionaries.

Comment: It's still not clear. Does the first JSON have the actual RFID tags in it or not? If it doesn't, now are those keys supposed to be matched up with the RFID tags in the other files?

Comment: I figured out how to do it. 

I will make the source JSON a list and not a dictionary, and then with the keys as lists in the script, I used 'zip' to create a dictionary using the same values for each of the 3 new files.